# Creating product page link

Tags: php

I am developing online store and to display detailed information of the products I have made **tourpage.php**.

Right now I am fetching details of each product using product id so link looks like **www.xyz.product.php?id=2**. But I want link to appear like this http://www.tours4fun.com/woodbury-common-premium-outlets-shopping-tour.html

I have created slug (woodbury-common-premium-outlets-shopping-tour.html) using php but whne i try to fetch it using this slug it shows up like www.xyz.com/tourpage.php/woodbury-common-premium-outlets-shopping-tour.html

=====QUESTION=====

how can I dynamically display each product with its own url like this www.xyz.com/woodbury-common-premium-outlets-shopping-tour.html

Comment: Look up .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Comment: Can you guide me on this? This is my very first time with developing a complete system from scratch.

Comment: It would be hard to explain here, but there are a lot of tutorials out there, including many for beginners.  You'll need to learn a small amount about regex, but it's not rocket surgery.  Here's a good one:  https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: In other words, you need to create a .htaccess file,  include the instructions and load it to the server.     If you are just getting started with these, they are pretty cool and quite powerful.  Here's a good starting place:   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: here's another:  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757

Comment: I am familiar with regular expressions. I will go through these links. Thanks

Comment: The first one is excellent.